# Maximum product of two elements in an array separated by 8 or more positions

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, time-complexity

Here's the problem and code that I've got so far.

I have a sequence of positive numbers. Length of a sequence is greater than 8 and a negative number (which is not a part of sequence) is a sign of an end of a sequence. I need to write a program (effective by time and memory usage) that finds the maximum product of 2 elements separated by 8 or more positions. It is guaranteed that the answer is less than 2000000000.

so for example, for `{1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 -1}` the answer would be `20`.

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static long long int find_max(long int *v1, long int size) {
    const int d = 8;
    long int arr[8];
    long int maxi = 0;  
    long long int max_pr = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < d + 1; i++) {
        arr[i % d] = v1[i - 1];
    }
    for (int j = d + 1; j < size + 1; j++) {
        if (arr[j % d] > maxi)
            maxi = arr[j % d];
        if (v1[j - 1] * maxi > max_pr)
            max_pr = v1[j - 1] * maxi;
        arr[j % d] = v1[j - 1];
    }
    return max_pr;
}

int main() {
    long int seq[100000];
    long int n = 0;

    while (n < 100000 && scanf("%ld", &seq[n]) == 1) {
        if (seq[n] < 0) {
            break;    //vector.push_back was too slow
        }
        n++;
    }

    long long int answer = find_max(seq, n);
    printf("%lld ", answer);

    return 0;
}
```

It is a homework question for an open course on algorithms and data structures which is not related to my degree. My code fails on the testing system. I've tried to solve this problem for a couple of days now and can't understand what I'm doing wrong here because it has worked fine for every example I could come up with.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please adhere to a sane brace style in the future. Your code was impossible to read before.

Comment: Also, can we get a hint? Can you provide a test case that fails? What exactly is wrong with your code?

Comment: @ReousaAsteron It was a part of task description. Just used as a sign of the end of the sequence since it's length is unknown. Yes, it would be totally fine if you remove it

Comment: @Barry I have no idea what is wrong and I don't have any examples of test cases, unfortunately. I send it to my course's  online testing system and it only says that it fails on test 8 and gives a wrong answer

Comment: You are assuming that the length of the sequence is at most 100000. Why? As gnasher729's answer shows, you don't need to allocate an array to store the whole sequence. And your code will certainly fail if the sequence contains more than 100000 elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is quite easily done in linear time without needing any extra storage. Think which numbers could be the possible solution: It could be first number times the ninth number. It could be the largest of the first two, times the tenth. It could be the largest of the first three, times the eleventh, and so on. So:

```
Set maxN = 0, maxProduct = 0, i = 0. 
As long as v1 [i + 8] ≥ 0:
    If v1 [i] > maxN then maxN = v1 [i]
    If v1 [i + 8] * maxN > maxProduct then maxProduct = v1 [i + 8] * maxN.
    Let i = i + 1.
```

That's it.

Comment: Thank you! I know it's an easy task and I understand logically how it should be done. What I've posted here is really not the first thing that I've tried.  Your solution fails on the same test that my code fails on

Comment: @marinazz: If you know it's an easy task and you understand logically how it should be done, why have you done it so badly? Reading all the elements into an array is a stupid thing to do.

Comment: @TonyK I meant that I understand the algorithm. I still do not understand how else should I get the elements from the input if not read them into array or vector. I am an absolute beginner and even if my whole question was stupid there was no need to be rude.

Comment: @marinazzz: Well, it seemed clear to me that gnasher729's algorithm only requires you to store the last 8 values.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is not doing what the question asks you to do. In particular, `arr[8]` and `i%d` are not necessary.

Here is how you can solve this problem in O(n) time, which is as efficient as it gets:

- Make an array `maxSoFar` of the size equal to the size of the array
- Walk the array `seq` left to right. Set `maxSoFar[i]` to the highest value of `seq` to the left of `i`
- Walk the array `seq` again starting at index `8`, and find `max` of `seq[i] * maxSoFar[i-8]`.

Here is an example of `maxSoFar` for a random sequence:

```
seq:             1 4 3 5 2 12  8  6 14 19  7  9 25 20 13
maxSoFar:        1 4 4 5 5 12 12 12 14 19 19 19 25 25 25
```

The second pass should produce these values:

```
seq:             1 4 3 5 2 12  8  6 14 19  7  9  25  20  13
maxSoFar[i-8]:   - - - - -  -  -  -  1  4  4  5   5  12  12
mul:             - - - - -  -  -  - 14 76 28 45 125 240 156
```

Hence, the result is 240.

**Note:** The array maxSoFar can be eliminated. Can you see how?

Comment: Nice, but not as efficient as gnasher729's elegant solution, because you need an extra **O(n)** space for the same time complexity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've tried both of the solutions that have been posted here, but none of them passed that same test my program failed on.

Comment: I think now that maybe the problem is in the main() part of the function.